# issue in hosting cakephp application with hybridauth plugin

Tags: hosting, cakephp-3.0, cpanel, hybridauth

I am newbie to cakephp3.. I developed one small application and used hybrid auth plugin for social login. everythig is working perfectly fine on my localhost but the moment i deployed it on cpanel, I am getting the error

```
Error: The application is trying to load a file from the ADmad/HybridAuth plugin. 

Make sure your plugin ADmad/HybridAuth is in the /home/thyaceas/public_html/mytesturl.com/mycake1/plugins/ directory and was loaded.
```

Can you please tell where i am going wrong.

Process to deploy the application:
I first installed the cakephp through scripts in cpanel
then I copied all my files in this folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you simply copy the src folder via FTP? I would guess that the bootstrap on your local machine differs from the one on your server.

Comment: so what should I do? Shall I copy all the content apart from bootstarp?

Comment: If you want to deploy via FTP I think you should copy the src and webroot folders. From the config folder copy the bootstrap.php file. Then have a look in the app.php and .env (if you're using those) and adjust the database connections, etc and add possibly new keys from you local file.  If you have ssh connection to your server, I'd suggest that you put your application under version control and deploy it from git and then do a composer update.

Comment: I again started it from fresh and did things as you said but getting the same error again. i installed the hybridauth plugin in local machine using composer seems that step is getting missed in case of cpanel. i dont know what is going wrong?

Comment: In your bootstrap.php there should be something like `Plugin::load('ADmad/HybridAuth');` Is that the case on your server?

Comment: Plugin::load('ADmad/HybridAuth', ['bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true]);

I have written like this

Comment: Did you copy over the vendor folder? The autoloader there is generated by composer and this should contain the correct namespace to the plugin. In your error message it is looking for the Plugin in /plugins folder.

Comment: I noticed that my plugin is in the vendor folder but error message says that it should be in plugins folder.. so i copied the folder from vendor folder to plugin folder but syill getting the same error

Comment: If it's working fine on your dev system with the plugin in the vendor folder, then it should work fine on the production system with it there, no need to go altering the directory structure. As @Seb asked, have you copied the *whole* vendor folder? Very important are `autoload.php` and the entire `composer` folder, as these together define the autoloading that helps PHP find your vendor classes.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I was copying only admad folder and not complete vendor folder. it is working now. thanks once again